# Reducing Docker image size for multi-module maven project

Tags: java, docker, maven, maven-assembly-plugin, multi-module

I have a multi-module Maven project consisting of two modules: `module1` and `module2`. Their dependencies, which are almost the same, are mostly defined in the parent `pom.xml`.

```
module1/
    src/...
    pom.xml
module2/
    src/...
    pom.xml
pom.xml
```

I'm struggling to create a Docker image that allows me to run `module1` and `module2` as executable jars, but does not copy the dependencies in the parent `pom.xml` twice?

### Update

To address some questions in the comments, I would like to create **one** docker image from which I can run executable jars for `module1` and `module2`. They do not depend on one and other and run completely separately. I want to create one image since (surely?!) it'll help conserve disk space on Docker host.

The parent `pom.xml` is:

```
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>parent</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOST</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<name>parent</parent>
<modules>
    <module>module1</module>
    <module>module2</module>
</modules>
<dependencies>
 ...
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Show your Dockerfile, please. And pom.xml

Comment: Do you copy both `module1` and `module2` to the same docker container? If so: why? If there is a dependency between these modules (e.g. from `module1` to `module2`), it should be sufficient to only copy the result of one module to the container. The "proper" approach would be to create a shallow jar and copy the dependencies in a separate (earlier) layer to the docker container. See, e.g. [how quarkus does copy the dependencies](https://quarkus.io/guides/building-native-image#creating-a-container-with-a-multi-stage-docker-build).

Comment: Why you can't copy the .m2 folder with the needed deps to both images before build?

Comment: One possible solution would be to use [rdfind](https://rdfind.pauldreik.se/) with the `-makesymlinks` option. This only works if there are files which are exact duplicates, though.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. I have updated my question with some more details.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to create one docker image from which I can run
> executable jars for module1 and module2. They do not depend on one and
> other and run completely separately. I want to create one image since
> (surely?!) it'll help conserve disk space on docker host.

Don't do that. It is probably a misuse of Docker.
If the application `module1` doesn't depend at all on the application `module2`, you should not try to couple them in the same image only to get one image instead of two images.
First, it will first the image bigger as individual one but overall it creates an undesirable coupling : code/configuration/changes on `module1` image may cause side effects on `module2` image and reversely. Besides it will also couple the lifecycle : you create a new version of the image of both applications while only one application may be changed.
Many serious drawbacks for a small advantages.